Definition of Weak Topology of the Duality
I am currently reading the book A Course in Convexity by Alexander Barvinok. When it comes to the Section 4 in Chpater 4 (P157), the book gives the following definition:
Let $\langle\rangle:E\times F\to\mathbb{R}$ be a duality. We can make $E$ and $F$ topological vector spaces in the following way:

A basic open set $U\subset E$ is a set of the type $U=\{e\in E:\alpha_i<\langle e,f_i\rangle<\beta_i\text{ for }i=1,\dots,m \}$,
where  $f_1,\dots,f_m\in F$ and
$\alpha_1,\beta_1,\dots,\alpha_m,\beta_m\in \mathbb{R}$. An open
set in $E$ is the union of some basic open sets.
A basic open set $W\subset F$ is a set of the type $W=\{f\in F:\alpha_i<\langle f,e_i\rangle<\beta_i\text{ for
}i=1,\dots,m \}$, where  $e_1,\dots,e_m\in E$ and
$\alpha_1,\beta_1,\dots,\alpha_m,\beta_m\in \mathbb{R}$. An open
set in $F$ is the union of some basic open sets.

We call this topology the weak topology of the duality.
I am comfused about the meaning of "this topology", the author seems to have skipped a step, beacuse we only makes $E$ and $F$ become topological vector spaces, but we don't define a topology on $E\times F$.
I believe that "this topology" should not be two topologies defined on $E$ and $F$ respectively, since the duality is defined on $E\times F$. From the way the author expressed it, I don't think that's what he meant.
Remark:
The book's definition seems to be flawed in some way. It defines duality in real vector space at first, then it introduces this definition ("weak topology of the duality"), and prompts the definition of duality in topological vector space. However, the first sentence in this definition refers to "a duality", there is a suspicion of circular reasoning here, unless E and F must be real space.
I think the word "duality" can be replaced by "non-degenerate bilinear form" here.

I don't understand how there is supposed to be any circular reasoning here. Can you elaborate?

I suppose he should really say "we call these topologies the weak topology of the duality". Of course, if you have topologies on $E$ and $F$, you also get one on $E \times F$.

The reason I mentioned there is circular reasoning: according to the order in the book, we first establish topologies on the sets $E$ and $F$ to make them topological vector spaces. Then, based on these two topologies, we define the duality defined on $E\times F$. However, in the first step of this process—establishing topologies on the sets $E$ and $F$—the concept of duality is already referenced. @Smiley1000

I also thought of this possibility, maybe it should be understood this way. @Smiley1000

I think you have misunderstood something. You need to start with the duality, and then starting from the duality, you obtain the associated weak topologies.
